# Converting String to Numeric in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I encountered a Problem after importing JSON-Data. Usually _to_numeric_ is working fine, but not in this Case. I have a column of strings Looking like this:
10.2100
10.2400
...

I am using Jupyter Notebook.
I have tried *astype()*, _infer_objects(), but still the data keeps behaving like string. I checked this by multiplying the column with 2 and get:
10.210010.2100
10.240010.2400
...

This is the Code:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame()
temp = pd.DataFrame()
for file in filelist:
    with open(path+file, "r", encoding="windows-1252") as f:
        xml_string = f.read()
        if xml_string.find("<") >= 0:
            json_string = convert_to_json(xml_string)
            flat = flatten_json.flatten(json.loads(json_string))
            temp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(flat, orient='index').transpose()
            df = df.append(temp, sort=False)

df = df.reset_index()
pd.to_numeric(df.['Telegram_PRC_VALS_STP_2_VAL_0_NUM'])
df['Telegram_PRC_VALS_STP_2_VAL_0_NUM'] = df['Telegram_PRC_VALS_STP_2_VAL_0_NUM']*2
´´´

Any ideas? As this is my first Question in here I hope I am meeting your expectations on decently asking Questions.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to reassign output of [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) back, because it is not inplace method:

```
df['Telegram_PRC_VALS_STP_2_VAL_0_NUM']=pd.to_numeric(df['Telegram_PRC_VALS_STP_2_VAL_0_NUM'])
```

Comment: thank you! I must have missed that combination.
I tried  df = df.infer_objects()  thinking that should work, but that column remained an object.